# ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush inside a nested ControlValueAccessor not working

Tags: angular

I have a situation where if I use OnPush in a nested CVA, the state of the control in the nested form does not update on submit unless I touch the actual control. You can see the state of the country control not updating to touched unless you touch this control. On the other hand if I remove OnPush from this component submitting the form will update the country as well.

Here is a sample in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-qeopc2-uxyf94)

app.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #clientForm="ngForm">
  <mat-form-field>
    First Name:
    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="firstName" />
    <mat-error *ngIf="profileForm.get('firstName').hasError('required')">Required</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <ng-container formGroupName="contact">
    <app-address formControlName="address"></app-address>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

address.component.html

```
<div [formGroup]="addressFormGroup">
  <mat-form-field>
    Street (touched: {{ addressFormGroup.get('street').touched }})
    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="street" />
    <mat-error *ngIf="addressFormGroup.get('street').hasError('required')">Required</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <div>
    <app-country [formControl]="country"></app-country>
  </div>
</div>
```

address.component.ts

```
export class AddressComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor, Validator {
  addressFormGroup: FormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
    street: this._formBuilder.control(null, Validators.required),
    city: this._formBuilder.control(null),
    country: this._formBuilder.control('', Validators.required),
  });

  onTouched: () => void = () => {};

  private _ngControl!: NgControl;
  formControl!: FormControl;

  constructor(
    private readonly _changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private readonly _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private readonly _parentFormGroup: FormGroupDirective
  ) {
    this._ngControl = inject(NgControl, { self: true, optional: true });
    this._ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
  }

  get country(): FormControl<any> {
    return this.addressFormGroup.get('country') as FormControl;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formControl = this._ngControl.control as FormControl;
    this.formControl.setValidators([this.validate.bind(this)]);
    this.formControl.updateValueAndValidity();

    this._parentFormGroup.ngSubmit.subscribe((item) => {
      console.log('submitted');
      this.addressFormGroup.markAllAsTouched();
      this.addressFormGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
      this._changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
    });
  }
```

country.component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
  Country (touched: {{ formControl?.touched }})
  <input matInput [formControl]="formControl" />
  <mat-error *ngIf="formControl.hasError('required')">Required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

country.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-country',
  templateUrl: './country.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./country.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class CountryComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

  constructor(private readonly _changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this._ngControl = inject(NgControl, { self: true });
    this._ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formControl = this._ngControl.control as FormControl;
  }
```